# PHP - adding elements to array - connection reset error in webbrowser

Tags: php, arrays, connection

Why adding elements to array by:

$arrayname[]=....

generates error in webbrowser: CONNECTION RESET...

Could it be a server configuration issue?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610420/php-timeout-connection-to-server-reset)?

Answer (score 0):

well, what php version, what are you adding to the array ??? 
i have only experinced this whenever php crashes so be sure that php doesnt crash , cause that causes a connection reset. (look though apache error log....)

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14